# Bootstrap accordion panels with button on body

Tags: javascript, html

I have a query that populates several panels. When I click a specific button inside the panel body, I would like to hide the panel and show the next one. The accordion is not working and I can't figure out why.

The HTML:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<?php   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultDespiste)){ ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Despiste # <?php echo $row['ordem']; ?>

      </div>
      <?php if ($row['ordem'] == 1) { ?>
      <div id="<?php echo $row['idDespiste']; ?>"  class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body" id="<?php echo $row['ordem']; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['textoDespiste']; ?>
            <br/><button class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="<?php echo $row['idDespiste']; ?>">Não resolveu</button>
                 <button id="Done">Resolveu</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <div id="<?php echo $row['idDespiste']; ?>"  class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body" id="<?php echo $row['ordem']; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['textoDespiste']; ?>
            <br/><button class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="<?php echo $row['idDespiste']; ?>">Não resolveu</button>
                 <button id="Done">Resolveu</button>
          </div>
      </div>      
      <?php }?>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>
```

My script:

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    if (active) $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
});
```

Is it the `data-target` that is wrong? Or should I try and build the function in a different way targeting the button parent panel, hiding it and showing the next one?

Comment: I think building the function to look at the parent panel would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example. I removed the php code to make it cleaner:

```js
var $accordion = $('#accordion');

$accordion.find('.panel-heading').on('click', function() {
  // uncomment the line below if you want to close other opened panels 
  $accordion.find('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
  $(this).siblings('.panel-collapse').collapse('toggle');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Heading 1</div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque quis nisl dictum, tempor sapien ut, sagittis neque.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Heading 2</div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Cras blandit mattis aliquam. Vestibulum magna ligula, tempor et eros in, ultricies sollicitudin dolor. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Heading 3</div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
      Vestibulum magna ligula, tempor et eros in, ultricies sollicitudin dolor. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for you reply. The thing is when I click the first panel I want the first panel to close and the second to open.

Comment: Are you sure you want that? Did you mean you want the first panel to close and the second to open when you click the **second** panel? If so, uncomment the `// $accordion.find('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');` line in my code and it will work that way.

Comment: That Is working but when I changed the click to my button class It Only Hides the first `<div>`. I changed the `$(this).siblings` to `$accordeon.find` and it opens all other `<div>`

Comment: Could you try running the snippet again, I uncommented the code? It should hide all but the one that was clicked on.